# Storing encrypted data in database using Security::Cipher

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using following code to encrypt some string:

```
$value = 'somevalue';
$key = Configure::read('Security.salt');

$encrypted = Security::cipher($value,$key);
$decrypted = Security::cipher($encrypted,$key);
```

It works fine, it encrypts/decrypts correctly. 
But I can't save encrypted value in database - I set value of field encrypted_data to `$encrypted` and after `save()` there is nothing in this field in database. When I change $encrypted to for example 'string' it saves 'string' correctly to `'encrypted_data'`.

So the problem might be that encrypted string contains some strange characters that database wont accept - how I can fix it? (Using mysql database with utf-8)

Comment: what is the type and the length of your 'encrypted_data' field in db

Comment: Could you show us `var_dump($encrypted);`?

Comment: var_dump = string 'đĚŇ\' (length=6), field type is varchar(50)

Comment: I highly recommend a behavioral approach here. there are existing behaviors that can easily be adjusted to your needs.

Comment: VARBINARY works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @AD7six no problem, done. OP - please accept the answer so others can benefit from your question!

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps use `base64_encode($encrypted)` after encryption and before you store into the database, and `base64_decode($encrypted)` before decryption.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `VARCHAR` doesn't support those characters. Instead, you should change the column to [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) to support characters outside of the UTF charset.